# What should i write if no unit is given : unit or units?

Tags: geometry

What should I write if no unit is provided in math problems?  Is it unit or units? If we calculate area then unit^2 or units^2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may not write anything. A pure number is a pure number; if the problem says that the lengths are in "units", then it's "units", "units^2" et cetera.

Comment: Thank u sir/madam

Comment: You can write "square units" or $\text{unit}^2$, though I think the first option looks nicer. Writing $\text{units}^2$ doesn't look right to me.

Comment: If no units are provided, I wouldn't introduce the term.  The area of a disk of radius r is $\pi r^2$.  No need to say "units" or "units$\mbox{}^2$ or anything else.  That's the way it is written most frequently.

Comment: Agreeing with others here, I would not indicate any units at all. However, the nature of this question suggests that it comes from a young student, and the truth is, many teachers insist on some sort of unit statement. Though it seems pointless to me, I will not argue with their reasoning, particularly since it does no harm. In that case, I would use $\text{unit}^2$. I would not try to make the notation plural, just as I would never call two square kilometers 2 $\text{kms}^2$.